Potree viewer: Feature to update color of selected points in Point Cloud
I am trying to update the color of point on Point Cloud loaded on Potree Viewer. I am able to selcet points but I am not able to change its color. I have tried this.
                const colors = new Float32Array(numPoints * 3);
            for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
                colors[i * 3] = defaultColor.r / 255;
                colors[i * 3 + 1] = defaultColor.g / 255;
                colors[i * 3 + 2] = defaultColor.b / 255;
            }

            // Add the color attribute to the geometry
            pointcloud.geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
            pointcloud.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
            pointcloud.geometry.needsUpdate = true;

